# Android app crashes while using jsoup and AsyncTask!(doesn't even start actually)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Am trying to get data from a website to my phone via the app!
so i tried the jsoup using AsyncTask so as to avoid the use of network on the main thread.
well all thats good but my app won't even start. the error it says is nullpointerexception
below is the code and the logcat snippet

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mt= new MyTask();
    mt.execute(URL);
    mytext =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
}
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{   
    Document doc;
    String abouttext;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        mytext.setText("please wait...");
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String...params){

    String url=params[0];
    Document doc;

    try{
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element about = doc.select("div.box-content").first();
    String abouttext = about.text();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return abouttext;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mytext.setText(result);
    }

}
```

and here is the log

```
09-21 18:50:36.746: E/Trace(778): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-21 18:50:37.445: D/AndroidRuntime(778): Shutting down VM
09-21 18:50:37.445: W/dalvikvm(778): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0x40a71930)
09-21 18:50:37.506: E/AndroidRuntime(778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 18:50:37.506: E/AndroidRuntime(778): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.web/com.example.web.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 18:50:37.506: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-21 18:50:37.506: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
```

Pls someone tell me what am doing wrong!
Thanks!

I'll post the whole log i guess

```
09-21 19:52:34.164: D/AndroidRuntime(796): Shutting down VM
09-21 19:52:34.194: W/dalvikvm(796): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.web/com.example.web.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at com.example.web.MainActivity$MyTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:37)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at com.example.web.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-21 19:52:34.244: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are declaring Document doc two times in scope,

I think your  return abouttext; is giving problem

Suppose if there is no server connection to server or server return error response then your about text will not contain anything, It will be null..

Try declaring initializing abouttext  before about.text() method and check if about.text is not setting null value to abouttext..

Comment: nope that din't work! I did like u said removed the second declaration of doc, then initialized abouttext to HI and then in next line wrote "abouttext=about.text();".yet it is showing the same error nullpointerException. anyother suggetions? one more think now the error pointer that is the line it show has changed and is pointing to mt.execute(URL); 09-21 19:18:53.447: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.example.web.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
which is the mt.execute(url)

Comment: before setting "abouttext=about.text();" are you checking is about.text() is empty or not...if(about.text().toString()!=null){abouttext=about.text();}else {abouttext="Text Not set";}

Comment: no, still not working. i doubt that it even reaches that place cause it still says unable to start!

Comment: And also...By default Jsoup follows redirects. However your problem can be caused by how the redirect ist done. If the website uses javascript for this, the connection wont get redirected since jsoup doesn't support javascript.

And that can be the reason ...

Comment: can you tell us what is URL is holding actually??

Comment: it still doesn't start!

Comment: Try with debugging line by line, by adding break point...surely you'll come to know where is the actual problem...

Answer (score 0):

one of the problem is that you are trying to update the UI component from background thread

```
 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //since async works on different thread it cannot update the ui so we need to run the updating task on UI thread
// use the below code wherever you are changing Ui, like in prexcute, postexecute

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Stuff that updates the UI

            }
        });
    }
```

And from the error it looks the problem is either the url or the query before check if the url is not NULL , for query the error occurs because in select() the css query is invalid, try changing the query.

use breakpoints to know which code is exactly crashing your app